# integer-only wildcards in grep

Tags: bash, macos, grep, wildcard

i have command that outputs a collection strings that look like this:

```
json.formats[0]].url = "https://example.com/ar.html"
json.formats[1].url = "https://example.com/es.html"
json.formats[2s].url = "https://example.com/ru.html"
json.formats[3].url = "https://example.com/pt.html"
json.formats[73].url = "https://example.com/ko.html"
json.formats[1502].url = "https://example.com/pl.html"
```

(there are many more instances, however for simpilcity's sake theyve been removed)

i can use the command below

```
myCmd | grep -e 'json\.formats\[.*\]\.url\ \=\ '
```

however i only want the wildcard to match integers, and to throw out non-integer matches. it gives me the following:

```
json.formats[0]].url = "https://example.com/ar.html"
json.formats[1].url = "https://example.com/es.html"
json.formats[2s].url = "https://example.com/ru.html"
json.formats[3].url = "https://example.com/pt.html"
json.formats[73].url = "https://example.com/ko.html"
json.formats[1502].url = "https://example.com/pl.html"
```

what i really want is this:

```
json.formats[1].url = "https://example.com/es.html"
json.formats[3].url = "https://example.com/pt.html"
json.formats[73].url = "https://example.com/ko.html"
json.formats[1502].url = "https://example.com/pl.html"
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```
myCmd | grep -E 'json\.formats\[[[:digit:]]+\]\.url = '
```

or:

```
myCmd | grep -E 'json\.formats\[[0-9]+\]\.url = '
```

`[[:digit:]]` is equivalent of `[0-9]` for most of the locales.

Comment: An empty string is not an integer: you want `\+` instead of `*` in that regex.

Comment: `\+` would require GNU grep, in a POSIX grep the equivalent BRE would be `\{1,\}` or `[0-9][0-9]*` but IMHO you should just use `-E` and `+` anyway as that's also POSIX.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I also prefer using -E in grep